# Bootstrap 3 columns uneven spacing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When implementing bootstrap 3-columns design, there is uneven spacing between columns, because bootstrap css defines col-md-4 with left and right padding = 15px.

So, the column in the middle gets double padding, therefore the spacing is 30px, and not 15px.

Here is a drawing showing what I mean. Is there any way to make equal spacing, SO THAT the spacing remained even after we switch to mobile device size?

having something like that

```
.col-md-4 { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; }
.col-md-4:first-child { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0px; }
.col-md-4:last-child { padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 15px; }
```

will work fine in desktop mode, but in mobile responsive mode, left column will be missing right padding, and right column will be missing left padding

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(2) {padding-left: 7.5px;padding-right: 7.5px;}
```

This would be more appropriate way to have equal paddings for all this tree columns , or if you want just have equal paddings and does'not matter if it would be 30px you can just remove row outside of columns which is not good way or you can put one .col-md-12 outside of your columns

Comment: Sure, however, in smartphone mode, all the boxes are aligned vertically one under another, only left and right boxes have padding=15, but the middle box has padding=7.5, not equal

Comment: in smartphone you can change column just add col-xs-12 or col-sm-12 to your columns and that must have equal paddings